# Magento 2 : Override template file (sales order email - gift card product)

Tags: magento2, sales-order, email-templates, order-email, gift-card

I have found that this file is used with `_getGiftcardOptions()` `vendor/magento/module-gift-card/Block/Sales/Order/Item/Renderer.php` that provides data to labels for gift card item in the Sales order confirmation email.

I am not much if there is any PHTML file that is also used with this process. As I am trying to update this gift card item data (i.e to add other product attributes as well in the email template) I need to override that template file.

Any thoughts on which template file is responsible for gift card products in email?

Comment: Have you used any extension for gift card product?

Comment: yes one extension is their, but their is on template file in it

Comment: I am using Magento ver. 2.4.1

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: You just need to write css then why you want to override phtml file?

Comment: no not just css i need to change structure also.

Comment: I have checked on this, it seems like there is some another default.phtml file used for "giftcard" item.
As call is not coming into  overridden default.phtml file in module for "giftcard" product for other product it does.

Comment: I have found a way to do that
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/332541/magento-2-override-template-file