# Magento 2 : override template file

Tags: magento2, template

Is their any way we can override below template file

```
Magento_Sales::email/items/order/default.phtml
```

which is defined in

```
vendor/magento/module-gift-card/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_renderers.xml
```

in module ?

I have tried -  **Vendor/Sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_renderers.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd" label="Email Creditmemo Items List" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers.default">
            <action method="setTemplate" >
                <argument name="sales.email.order.renderers.default" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Sales::email/items/order/default.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="sales.email.order.renderers">
            <action method="setTemplate" >
                <argument name="sales.email.order.renderers.giftcard" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Sales::email/items/order/default.phtml</argument>
           </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

but then the file for "`sales.email.order.renderers.default`" block did not override.

Answer (score 0):

"setTemplate" replacing the template for given block in your "Vendor_Sales" module layout file. So original file override will not reflect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is their any other way ?

Comment: @devhs can you please explain a bit more what final output you are expecting(purpose of the override).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding it like this:

Override template file in your theme

```
app/design/frontend/{{vendor_namespace}}/{{theme_name}}/Magento_Sales/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i am not using theme

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">vendor_module::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```